# Merging the wifi tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We currently have a plethora of tags that can mean [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi)

- [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi) - 5148 questions
- [wlan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wlan) - 315 questions
- [wireless-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless-connection) - 119 questions
- [wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless) - 1149 questions

I didn't want to unilaterally merge them all without some community discussion. If you disagree with this (or there's tags I missed) please speak up.

Comment: wireless-connection and wireless are a bit weaker, because they could also cover the likes of bluetooth, as indeed [some do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699983/utra-wideband-and-bluetooth-simulators)

Comment: [wireless-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless-keyboard) only has 1 question (35 views, 0 votes, 0 answers)

Comment: @0-1 Fixed via tag edit

Comment: FWIW, we also have [tag:wificonfiguration] and [tag:wifi-configuration]. The latter has 0 questions. [tag:wifi-configuration] seems to be merged with [tag:wifi] as well. Shouldn't we merge [tag:wificonfiguration] with [tag:wifi]?

Comment: @10 `wifi-configuration` is a synonym of `wifi`, that's why it shows zero Q's

Comment: @zcoop98 I realize that, so I'm proposing synonymizing [tag:wificonfiguration] with [tag:wifi] as well.

Comment: Agreed. If [tag:wifi-configuration] is synonomized with [tag:wifi], then [tag:wificonfiguration] *definitely* should be. Those shouldn't be separate tags to begin with.

Comment: What about [tag:802.11]? The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/802.11/info) references WLAN, but is it useful to retain a distinct tag for the standard/ spec itself? Looks like [85/ 228 total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/802.11+wifi) 802.11 Q's are tagged "wifi" as well.

Comment: @zcoop98 In practice, I am not aware of a currently used wifi standard not owning to the 802.11 family! In the past, there used to be some ETSI Hiperlan standards ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Merge only the tags related to Wifi *only*:** [wlan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wlan), [802.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/802.11), [wifi-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi-configuration), and [wificonfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wificonfiguration) should be collapsed into [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi), while [wireless-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless-connection) and [wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless) should be burninated.

As mentioned in the comments, [wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless) can also refer to other wireless communication, such as Bluetooth. It should probably be subject to burnination/manual retagging to either [wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi) or [bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) (whichever applies).

Comment: I think [tag:wireless-connection] should just be merged into [tag:wireless].

Comment: @S.S.Anne I'm fine with that, but IMO they should both be burninated

Comment: If they can mean several things, then shouldn't they be burninated?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Yea, that's kinda what I meant by manual retagging, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @VFDan, with one exception: we should *not* leave [wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless) or [wireless-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireless-connection) alone. As he points out, these can mean several things. That being said, they should be burninated entirely (rather than left in place).

Comment: We really need a separate burninate request for just that for that. But the tags are merged, so that should make it simpler